# GetProperty umbraco C#

Tags: c#, umbraco

I really can't understand why this happens and I'm stuck. I can't find a way to do this. So the problem is that `member.GetProperty().Value.ToString()` is not doing fine. If I do this
`member.GetProperty("test").Value.ToString()` it works, but if instead I want to do it dynamicly it does not :( This is one part of the code (the one that matters for the case)

```
Member currentMem = Member.GetCurrentMember();
int memberId = currentMem.Id;

Member member = new Member(memberId);
int count = 0;
while (count < list.count)
{
    member.getProperty(list[count]).Value = does not matter //
    count++;
}
```

It's as simple as that, what I can't understand is why it does not work. It says "object not set as an instance of an object", why is that? :/ But if i gave him a "default" value it works like this

```
while (count < list.count)
{
    member.getProperty(list[1]).Value = does not matter //
    count++;
}
```

Thanks for reading my post, I hope you can help me :)

Comment: what is type of member?

Comment: What is the value of `count` when the error is thrown? If you're working with a dynamic property and trying to reference a value that doesn't exist, it's no wonder the code is throwing an exception.

Comment: It would seem like your list contains something that isn't a member property.  Can you validate the contents of the list and the member properties?  You might also need to validate you actually have a member before calling .getProperty().

Comment: Hey guys and btw thanks for trying to help me. @HaseebAsif Updated my post with that.

Comment: @LightningShield i already validated the content of the list , and its all properties and yes i get the member id before this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the order of the list is important. I just needed to create a `SortedList` instead of `List`.